# Android + iOS app + Firebase + Laravel CMS

Tags: android, ios, laravel, firebase, firebase-hosting

So, we are developing an Uber-like app (employer and employee apps), for the 3 platforms (Android, iOS and web), we are using firebase so far, but we ran into a small problem, all our experience in web development has been with laravel and PHP using standard shared hosting (GoDaddy and the sort). So we have no idea where to host the laravel part of the web considering firebase hosting doesn't run php.  Upon some research we hit this:

1. Firebase: Just the DB
2. Hosting: where we will place all of our php files like we normally do.
3. Laravel: In the controllers, we would access the DB by using firebase like a DB.

Is this the correct way to do it? or is there a better, more efficient way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't go with shared hosting for such an application. Shared hosting is shared across multiple users and might slow down your application because of other usage. Also it is limited in the number of processes that can run on the server also killing performance.

Try to research more about AWS or something like Digital Ocean. You can use Digital Ocean as a start since it is the least complicated VPS type hosting to use and has a good community for help.